# How to update unique items in a TArray

Tags: c++, unique, unreal-engine4

I'm adding and updating unique items in a `TArray`* using the following method.

```
USTRUCT() struct FMyObject
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    UPROPERTY(SaveGame) // example for serialization
    FName key;
    UPROPERTY(SaveGame) // example for serialization
    int someContent;
}

UCLASS() class FMyObjectOwner : public UObject
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    AddOrReplaceUnique(const FMyObject& newObject)
    {
        // Remove possibly existing entry.

        const auto index = myObjects.IndexOfByKey(newObject.key);
        if (index != INDEX_NONE)
        {
            myObjects.RemoveAtSwap(index, 1, false);
        }

        // Add new.
        myObjects.Add(newObject);
    }
    UPROPERTY(SaveGame) // example for serialization
    TArray<FMyObject> myObjects;
}
```

Is there a shorter or more convenient way (removing and adding in one call?) to update unique items in a `TArray` using UnrealEngine >= 4.24?

---

*I'm using a `TArray` instead of a `TMap` or a `TSet` since I want it to be garbage collected and to be serialized. I'm not sure if both is supported by the latter container types.

Comment: It sounds like you might benefit from a `TSet` over a `TArray` here, which is built to only hold unique items. Then you can just simply update the item inside the set instead of doing a full swap operation. Something like `if(mySet.Contains(newObject)){ //Update it } else { //add it }`

Comment: @BenjaFriend The `Contains` check is redundant in a `TSet`. The only thing you need to call is `Add`.

Comment: @BenjaFriend True. However, the question was specifically for cases where a `TMap`or `TSet` are not applicable (made this more explicit in the question). Also when using a `TSet`, I think the `FMyObject` needs a hash function for its key property.